# Custom Excel VBA Hotkey for "Go To Previous Sheet"

Tags: excel, object, spreadsheet, hotkeys, vba

I am attempting to make a custom hotkey that will go to the previous sheet viewed.

As far as I understand, this would involve making a Class Module as a Worksheet object that will capture Sheet Change, Sheet Activate, and Sheet Deactivate Events.  Once the event has been captured, I would set the previous active worksheet to an object variable.  Then I would make a custom macro that would go to the previously set worksheet object once a hotkey is pressed.  Is this the right path?

And if it is the right path, where would I save the Macro code so that it's usable by all future workbooks?  I have a PERSONAL.xlsb file created and ready to edit.  Would I make the class module in PERSONAL.xlsb?  How would I initialize the object in PERSONAL.xlsb when I create a new workbook?

Answers to these questions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Generally on the right line, but:

- you only need the `Deactivate` event to capture the last sheet
- to code this for all workbooks, you would use an `Application` level event handler.  See [cPearson site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)
- you may want to handle `WorkbookDeactivate` as well
- I would create a class event handler (as described in the link) including a property for the last sheet, and a Module level Sub to get the LastSheet from the class, and activate it